# Using RDA in R with just one dataset

Tags: r, statistics, rda

This is possibly a stupid question, but I was told to do a Redundancy Analysis in R (using the package Vegan) to test the differences between different groups in my data. However I only have one dataset (roughly comparable to the Iris dataset (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)), and everything I have found on RDA seems to need two matching sets. Did I mishear or misunderstand, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the underlying statistics are concerned, you have two data matrices;

1. the four morphological variables in the `iris` data set
2. a single categorical predictor variable or *constraint*

In **vegan** using `rda()` for this and the `iris` example data you'd do:

```
library("vegan")
iris.d <- iris[, 1:4]
ord <- rda(iris.d ~ Species, data = iris)
ord

set.seed(1)
anova(ord)
```

The permutation test, tests for differences between species.

```
> anova(ord)
Permutation test for rda under reduced model
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: rda(formula = iris.d ~ Species, data = iris)
          Df Variance      F Pr(>F)    
Model      2   3.9736 487.33  0.001 ***
Residual 147   0.5993                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

You might also look at `adonis()`, which should do the same thing here as RDA but from a different view point:

```
> adonis(iris.d ~ Species, data = iris)

Call:
adonis(formula = iris.d ~ Species, data = iris) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

           Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
Species     2   2.31730 1.15865  532.74 0.87876  0.001 ***
Residuals 147   0.31971 0.00217         0.12124           
Total     149   2.63701                 1.00000           
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

(For some reason that is a lot slower...)

Also see `betadisper()` as you might detect a difference in means (centroids) using these methods where that may be due at least in part to differences in variance (dispersion).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I've tried this code out with the iris dataset and am having some troubles -

After: ord <- rda(iris.d ~ Species, data = iris)

I keep getting the error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = iris.d ~ Species, data = iris) :  invalid type (list) for variable 'iris.d'